# Python script to read the database tables and relation to create dot file

Tags: python, dot

Hi I am new to dot file concept,

I am looking create ERD diagram with Primary keys and relationships. The approach is to whip up a Python script to read the database tables and to create a "dot" file which can then be used to generate the graphic using graphviz. I found the way to generate graph using dot file on graphviv.org, however I didn't found the way to use Python script to read the database tables and to create a "dot" file. Any help would really appreciate, thanks.

Comment: Is the problem the reading of the database, or the generation of the dot file, or both? What type of database are you using? I think you need to add more information in order to get useful answers.

Comment: I am using DB2, the problem is I dont know how I should flow as this is first time I am working on python and dot. if you could share any sample python script that reads the data from any database and creates a dot file would work for me. please let know if you need any more information.

Comment: welcome to SO. If you need to clarify your question note you always can re-edit it using trhe 'edit' label at its bottom

Answer (score 2):

for graphviz modules you can check [this](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=graphviz&submit=search)
for database manipulation, it depends on the size and complexity of your data, but you can start with the [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) python module

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a crude script to do exactly this. It works only for mySQL for an engine that understands foreign keys (myISAM doesn't work). It does text parsing to get the keys and stuff so it's not as robust as one would expect. I wrote it quickly to analyse a medium sized database that I had to work on for a consulting project. Most of the parameters will have to be tweaked to work properly for you but you might be able to start off with it.

The code is available [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577298-plot-database-table-dependecies-for-a-mysql-databa/?in=user-4173873) and here is a scaled down version of an example database graphed by the tool.

[image: database plot]